# Doubt on Short Circuiting

Tags: electricity

If during a short circuit, the resistance becomes negligible then what is the reason for getting the wire heated?

Comment: "If during a short circuit, the resistance becomes negligible" - what resistance? what are you short circuiting?... "what is the reason for getting the wire heated" - what wire?

Comment: @TomCarpenter "A common type of short circuit occurs when the positive and negative terminals of abattery are connected with a low-resistanceconductor, like a wire. With a low resistance in the connection, a high current will flow, causing the delivery of a large amount ofenergy in a short period of time.". -Wikipedia. It says that the resistance becomes zero. Why?

Comment: Ok, so what don't you understand about that quote?

Comment: Why does the wire get heated even if the resistance is negligible?

Comment: Where does it say the resistance becomes zero? Only a superconductor would do that. The resistance will be whatever the resistance of the wire is, which is small, yes. Given than power dissipated in a resistor is \$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\$, if \$R\$ is small, power dissipated is going to be high.

Comment: The short circuit resistance is not really negligible in many circumstances. See Tony Stewart's diagram. Unless the short circuit is much less than the other resistances, it is not negligible. Some high-power lithium ion 18650 cells can supply over 100 A during short circuit. I have seen 150 A myself during testing.

Comment: @mkeith I said as according to Wikipedia

Answer (score 1):

The resistance can be negligible for one purpose (figuring out the current drawn from the battery), but not negligible for another purpose (figuring out how much the wire heats up).

In the first case, the wire resistance becomes negligible when it is "much less than" the internal resistance of the battery.

In the second case, the wire resistance isn't negligible because you're considering an effect where some other resistance will dominate the behavior. When you're calculating the self-heating of a resistor (or wire), having already determined the current, the only resistance that matters is the resistance of that wire itself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a short circuit with zero resistance unless you start to talk about superconductors. A "short circuit" is simply some construct with very low resistance.
Any connection you can create in normal electronic or electrical circuits will have some resistance.

If you are shorting out a battery with a screwdriver for example, the battery has internal resistance and the chrome steel screwdriver has resistance. 
The screwdriver will get hot and the battery will get hot ....because of their resistance.

Comment: According to Wikipedia-.                 negligible
-
adjective

so small or unimportant as to be not worth considering; insignificant.
                         I hope you get it!

Comment: Unfortunately your comment simply shows your total lack of knowledge or understanding of Resistance, or of the heating that might occur due to current flowing through it.

Comment: I have now understood the cause by the brilliant given answers. By the way, which comment are you talking about. Could you please mention?

Comment: Directly above ..."According to Wikipedia...."

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will work on my concepts. That According to Wikipedia was posted by me so that I can make Jack creasey realize that I have not mentioned anything like zero but instead mention "negligible". The definition was to make him realize. Well As I learned about resistance a month before only as I am in 8th grade

Comment: The use of "negligible" is relative to an application. As an 8th Grader you have so much more to learn yet. Enjoy the journey.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a short circuit condition you're essentially putting a very small resistance across your supply.

If you've got a fixed voltage and your resistance is very low, then the current becomes high, as per Ohm's law: \$I = \frac V R\$

Heat is generated when power is dissipated in a material. In this case, power is proportionate to the *square* of the current: \$P = I^2R\$.

So, if let's say you've got a 12V supply and you short it out with a 0.1Ω resistance:

$$I=\frac V R = \frac {12} {0.1}=120\mathrm{A}$$

$$P=I^2R=120^2\times0.1=1440\mathrm{W}$$

Power is just energy over time (1 Joule per second) so what's essentially happening in this example is you've got 1440 Joules of electrical energy being converted to heat (and light if the wire glows) every second.

Comment: Nice answer. 

Answer (score 1):

If power is dumped into a short circuit, the part with the highest resistance will dump the most power and get hot. (unless the supply shuts down)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIiuEW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Every conductor has resistance even if very low.  LiPo cells are 5~25mΩ, Wire resistance tables for AWG tell you mΩ/m.  Switches rated for 10A might be `1mΩ when new, 10mΩ when old and oxidized.